# Restrict Service Account User role with IAM Conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I'd like to grant `Service Account User` role to a certain identity, but only on service accounts whose name starts with a given prefix. Is it possible to do that with IAM Conditions?

I've tried the following condition

```
{
    "expression": "resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/-/serviceAccounts/prefix-\")",
    "title": "test-condition"
}
```

and it doesn't work, while when I remove `prefix-`, it does (but obviously not desired).

Perhaps I should use a request-based expression instead, but it's unclear what the request looks like, as `actAs` is not among the [documented API calls](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts), and I cannot find these requests in Cloud Audit logging either.

UPDATE: I've just realized that `actAs` expects the following form of the `resource.name`:

```
projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{UNIQUE_ID}
```

And indeed, when I specify the unique numeric ID of one of the SAs, it works. The challenge is though, I'd like to grant it based on the service account name prefix..

Comment: I think you can't. But you can grant the role at the service account level directly and not at the project level with an IAM condition. Should not be easier? Or maybe, you want to enforce automatically this permission in case of new service account are created, without granting any permission directly on the newly created service account.

Comment: Yes, the challenge we're trying to overcome with this is to avoid the extra management overhead of granting it for each individual SA (of which we have many, so not possible to do without extra automation). So I'd still like to find conditions that could work.

Comment: This is not currently possible, however, there is currently a Feature Request ongoing to allow regular expression matching on resource for Conditions  [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/204085257)

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo - could you clarify, how that would help in this case? Since `resource.name` in `actAs` API call (which is perhaps a private API on the Google backend?) sends the numeric ID of the SA, and therefore doesn't seem to be suitable for matching with a regex.

Comment: @dinvlad i'm trying to do what you achieved to do for one service account (not a prefix), what is the syntax of your working expression? I tried `resource.name == "projects/{PROJECT_ID}/serviceAccounts/{UNIQUE_ID}"` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @NicolasKarolak that's the syntax, as far as I could tell. Is there any error that it gives you?